# Reasons for structure of standard exception hierarchy

Tags: c++

This is a picky thing and it is probably just my OCD flairing up but I was wondering why the standard exception class hierarchy is set up as it is.

```
exception
  bad_alloc
  bad_cast
  bad_typeid
  bad_exception
  ios_base::failure
  runtime_error
    subclasses...
  logic_error
    subclasses...
```

Couldn't all the bad_* exceptions just be subclasses of something like lang_support_error?  And ios_base::failure seems completely out of place.

Is there some historical or technical reasons the hierachy ended up like this?

Comment: Just goes to show how hard (and essentially pointless) it is to  design exception hierarchies :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the logic was:

- `logic_error` would be the equivalent of an `assert`, but with less drastic behavior
- `runtime_error` would be the base of all others

However, as you noticed, it does not quite hold, even in the standard library itself.

The main issue I guess is subjectivity: is `std::out_of_range` a `logic_error` or a `runtime_error` ?

It's subjective...